# Is it possible to give a variable a default value

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to give variables a default value if theyre not defined onload?

I have variables in my script which need multiplying, only they take the value from input fields so on load they're all null...

Code:

```
var conMin = document.getElementById('cMin').value; 
var serLev = document.getElementById('sLev').value; 
var coreHrs = conMin * serLev * noFrames; 
var noFrames = 1800
```

Comment: Can you post your script? My best guess is that you are overcomplicating things :)

Comment: Why don't you give the input fields default values?

Comment: `code`var conMin = document.getElementById('cMin').value;
 var serLev = document.getElementById('sLev').value;
 var coreHrs = conMin * serLev * noFrames;
 var noFrames = 1800;`code`

Comment: `var something = 'defaultValue';`

Comment: The code would be better edited into the answer so it could be formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```
var conMin = document.getElementById('cMin').value || 'cMin_default'; 
var serLev = document.getElementById('sLev').value || 'sLev_default';
```

The variable will be assigned the value on the right if the value on the left is false, 0, "", null, or undefined.

Comment: If the variable has been set to a value that isn't true (such as `0`), then that value will be overwritten by the default.

Comment: @LG87 — An or operator will return the left hand side if the left hand side is true, otherwise it will return the right hand side.

Comment: @LG87: yet the explanation is what quentin said.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof someVar === "undefined") {
    someVar = 'a default';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things.

As has already been suggested, you can populate the input fields with default values as one possibility.

As another, rather than pull the values straight from the input fields, do some validation as you bring them in and store them in variables (i.e. variables as in `var` variables, not variables as in those in the `document`).  This will give you a chance to check to see if the value is appropriate and if it's blank, fill in a default, like so:

```
var conMin = '2'; //or whatever default value you want
if (document.getElementByID('cMin').value != '') {
    conMin = document.getElementByID('cMin').value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Ive tried this now, only when I try to multiply the 3 variables its still returning NaN, have you any idea what causes this?

Comment: Because they are strings.  You have to convert them to integers first using `parseInt`